# One page losing session variables?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one page in an asp.net project that is losing the session variables after it's loaded, and with any browser. There are around 50 pages in the project, and all others work fine, except this one page.

The page loads fine, and the session items are there at page load (I checked by adding some asp labels to view them), but not on postback or if you navigate away from this page. It only has a gridview that populates from several databases, all on the same server, and an asp menu for navigation. It is InProc, not using a web farm, not using response.redirect, and I've checked with fiddler and the session is not recycling.

I've commented out all code on both the aspx and vb page and replaced it with code from another working page in the project and it makes no difference. What else should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
add new aspx page. 
copy content from your old page to this aspx page. (HTML and Javascript)
copy server side code this new page too.

and see if its help. some time very strange issues are resolved by just creating new page.

If problem still exists, comment all the code and uncomment them one by one and see where you lose the session.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of the page and it worked.

Turns out the master page load event had a line to abandon the session if not postback and the request url had "Login" in it. The page in question was a view of recent logins called LastLogin, so it was abandoning the session on page load.

Comment: I edited your answer, say thanks in the comments not as an answer.  Read the FAQ of the site for more info.